# $ not a function in flexslider in the code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I used this code to send data to server and get data but confront flexslider error when running the code. I check I don't have two jquery script in the code and I there is just one.

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="submit"
"onclick="onSubmit()">check</button>
<label>result</label>
<textarea id="textresult"></textarea>

                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- bootstrap -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- isotope -->
        <script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
        <!-- images loaded -->
        <script src="js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
        <!-- wow -->
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <!-- smoothScroll -->
        <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
        <!-- jquery flexslider -->
        <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <!-- custom -->
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slidercode.js"></script>    
        <script src="js/newpage.js"></script>
```

newpage file contain the onSubmit function as :

```
function onSubmit()
{
    var text = $('#textarea').val();
     $.ajax({
           method: 'post',
           data: {text: text },

           dataType: 'json',
           url: "xxxxx",
           success: function(result) {
                           alert('success');

           successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            return data;
            handleData(data); 
          },

         error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
    });
}

function handleData (data) {
document.getElementById("textresult").innerHTML = data;
}

function onReset(){
document.getElementById("textarea").value = "";
document.getElementById("textresult").value = "";


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery first

```
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/newpage.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
 <script src="js/newpage.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: at the end of the script you have included <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 move in place of js/jquery.js

Comment: error, unrecognized expression: .navbar-default a, a,
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: jquery include should be first and then include the bootstrap. after this you can included what ever your scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185044/discussion-between-seravee-and-user123).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, reason as follows:

1. Write all code inside

   $(document).ready(function(){
      function onSubmit(){
      }
      . . .
   });
2. Use JQuery instead of $
3. jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
              function onSubmit(){
              }
              . . .
       });